# Abelian von Neumann Algebras on non-separable Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Is there a classification of Abelian von Neumann algebras on non-separable Hilbert spaces? For a classification of Abelian von Neumann algebras on separable Hilbert spaces, see this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_von_Neumann_algebra).

Comment: According to this [link](http://planetmath.org/ClassificationOfHilbertSpaces.html), for any Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to $l^2(I)$ where $I$ is a set having cardinality equal to the dimension of $H$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every commutative von Neumann algebra $A$ is $^*$-isomorphic to $L_\infty(\Omega,\mu)$ for some locally compact Hausdorff space and positive measure $\mu$.

Idea of the proof is the following. Decompose
$$
A\cong\coprod\limits_{\nu\in\Lambda} A_\nu
$$
into the coproduct of commutative von Neumann algebras with cyclic vector. For every commutative von Neumann algebra $A_\nu$ with cyclic vector there exist compact Hausdorff space $\Omega_\nu$ and regular bounded Borel measure $\mu_\nu$, such that $A_\nu$ is $^*$-isomorphic to $L_\infty(\Omega_\nu,\mu_\nu)$. Then one can show that
$$
A\cong L_\infty\left(\coprod\limits_{\nu\in\Lambda} \Omega_\nu,\coprod\limits_{\nu\in\Lambda} \mu_\nu\right)
$$

See Theory of operator algebras Part I by M. Takesaki, chapter 3, theorem 1.18.

Comment: Ok, this means that classification of abelian von Neumann algebras reduces to classification of compact Hausdorff spaces, right? But for the latter, there is not really a classification...you can't say that there exist finitely many compact Hausdorff spaces such that any compact Hausdorff space is homeomorphic to one of these...?

Comment: You don't need to classify all Hausdorff spaces, just hyperstonean ones. But anyway it is too big class of topological spaces, to be well classified.